# Get user location LAT LNG using GPS and network

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying to get lat and lng and want to show that in a text box I want both mean Network address and GPS address so I have done this **But every time I am getting only one address at a time**

```
public class GetLocationMainActivity extends Activity {

double nlat;
double nlng;
double glat;
double glng;

LocationManager glocManager;
LocationListener glocListener;
LocationManager nlocManager;
LocationListener nlocListener;

TextView textViewNetLat;
TextView textViewNetLng;
TextView textViewGpsLat;
TextView textViewGpsLng;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_location_main);

    //All textView
    textViewNetLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewNetLat);
    textViewNetLng = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewNetLng);
    textViewGpsLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewGpsLat);
    textViewGpsLng = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewGpsLng);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    //Remove GPS location update
    if(glocManager != null){
        glocManager.removeUpdates(glocListener);
        Log.d("ServiceForLatLng", "GPS Update Released");
    }

    //Remove Network location update
    if(nlocManager != null){
        nlocManager.removeUpdates(nlocListener);
        Log.d("ServiceForLatLng", "Network Update Released");
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

//This is for Lat lng which is determine by your wireless or mobile network
public class MyLocationListenerNetWork implements LocationListener  
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        nlat = loc.getLatitude();
        nlng = loc.getLongitude();

        //Setting the Network Lat, Lng into the textView
        textViewNetLat.setText("Network Latitude:  " + nlat);
        textViewNetLng.setText("Network Longitude:  " + nlng);

        Log.d("LAT & LNG Network:", nlat + " " + nlng);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.d("LOG", "Network is OFF!");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.d("LOG", "Thanks for enabling Network !");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}

public class MyLocationListenerGPS implements LocationListener  
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        glat = loc.getLatitude();
        glng = loc.getLongitude();

        //Setting the GPS Lat, Lng into the textView
        textViewGpsLat.setText("GPS Latitude:  " + glat);
        textViewGpsLng.setText("GPS Longitude:  " + glng);

        Log.d("LAT & LNG GPS:", glat + " " + glng);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.d("LOG", "GPS is OFF!");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.d("LOG", "Thanks for enabling GPS !");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}

public void showLoc(View v) {

    //Location access ON or OFF checking
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
    boolean gpsStatus = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean networkWifiStatus = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    //If GPS and Network location is not accessible show an alert and ask user to enable both
    if(!gpsStatus || !networkWifiStatus)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GetLocationMainActivity.this);

        alertDialog.setTitle("Make your location accessible ...");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Your Location is not accessible to us.To give attendance you have to enable it.");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.warning);

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Remember to give attandance you have to eanable it !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
    //IF GPS and Network location is accessible
    else 
    {
        nlocManager   = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        nlocListener = new MyLocationListenerNetWork();
        nlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                1000 * 1,  // 1 Sec        
                1,         // 1 meter   
                nlocListener);


        glocManager  = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        glocListener = new MyLocationListenerGPS();
        glocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                1000 * 1,  // 1 Sec        
                1,         // 1 meter           
                glocListener);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you requesting permission for both fine and coarse location data?  You need to do both.

Comment: I did not get your point please explain

Comment: In your manifest, you need to request permission to get location data.  There's 2 permissions-  fine and coarse.  You need both if you want network and gps data.

Comment: yes yes I had added those two

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable both NETWORK-LOCATION and GPS-LOCATION in Settings yet? As far as I know for Android ICS (4.x) and newer, due to the Security issue, you can't enable/disable location access programmatically. Try to test it on Android 2.x. Hope this helps.

Comment: Where did you call your showLoc() method? Otherwise there will be no requestLocationUpdates and you only get one and only location.

Comment: it was called from a button click

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new fused provider to get the user location quickly without confuse.

Location issues has been simplified with the new Google Play Services such as choosing best provider automatically depending on your priority.

Here is an example request;

```
    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
        .setInterval(20000) // 20 seconds
        .setFastestInterval(16) // 16ms = 60fps
        .setNumUpdates(4)
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

Make sure you updated the Google Play Services in the SDK Manager and check out this link to get info about how to get users location with the new Play Services. 
http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html